# Blender's 2.7 Texture View in Blender 2.8 - How do I remove all the shadows?

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I'm not very good with Blender so please bear with me. I use Blender to create models for a game that I'm working on. The game doesn't have any light sources so all the shadows and highlights are drawn directly into the textures. In Blender 2.7 there was a "texture view" button which showed my 3d model and the texture on top of it without any sort of lights or shadows. I understand that in Blender 2.8 this has to be done via the node editor where you create a material which you then apply to your object and by using Dev Look you can achieve the same result. I've done that and it's almost there, but I still have some soft shadows on my characters such as around his chin, armpits and so forth. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!
 [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *Workbench* engine for this purpose. In the render tab set lighting to *Flat* and color to *Texture*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that's perfect!